# Resizable NSDatePicker with graphical mode

Tags: macos, appkit, nsdatepicker

I want to add a NSDatePicker in the sidebar of my app, to help select dates. The standard NSDatePicker only seems to come in a single size, and doesn't seem to be resizable. I've dropped the NSDatePicker component into a xib file, and added auto-layout constraints, but they don't seem to work. Is there a way to make them respond to auto-layout and be resizable? Or should I be looking for 3rd-party frameworks to integrate with (if so, any recommendations)?

Comment: Which style and elements?

Comment: As a graphical date picker.

Comment: Do you want to add padding or do you want to scale the date picker?

Comment: Ideally both. Padding on the sides w.t.r. superview, and scaling the date picker (at least horizontally) as a view is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the date picker in a superview. Set the bounds of the superview and the date picker will stretch.

```
class MyScaledView: NSView {

    @IBOutlet weak var wrappedSubView: NSView! // date picker
    
    override func layout() {
        super.layout()
        bounds = wrappedSubView.frame
    }
    
}
```

Constrain the location of the date picker but not its size. For example add constraints for leading and bottom space.